# Fill array in PHP using Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing an android application that uses PHP and makes requests with Mysql. Initially I tested all the features on the local server to then migrate it to an online server, in this case, Hostinger.

One of my PHP files returns the value of an array correctly on the local server, however, when using the same PHP file on the online server with the same database, the array only responds to TRUE when I run `echo`.

I tried doing the echo of each line and it is working perfectly, just not being able to associate the values with the keys in the array.

```
$result= mysqli_query($connect, $sql);


while ($patients= $result->fetch_assoc()){  
    echo $patients['group'];              //prints OK
    echo $patients['exercise_name'];      //prints OK
    echo $patients['use_exercise'];       //prints OK

            $insert[] = array("group" => $patients['group'],    
                                 "name" => $patients['exercise_name'],
                                 "use" => $pacientes['use_exercise']
                                ); 

      }

echo json_encode($insert);  //prints TRUE
```

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($insert);` before echoing out the JSON?

Comment: In your array setting - `$pacientes` is not `$patients`

Comment: My var_dump:
´bool(true)´

Comment: Nigel, I forgot to translate this part, but it's correct here.

Comment: If it's correct, then please put your full code in the question and no need to edit it.  Please include your SQL as well.

Comment: When I don't use $insert as an array, it prints correctly, but just for the last row. 
{"group":"ankle","name":"ankle_3","use":"0"}

Comment: Have you tried properly initializing `$insert` as an empty array before your loop …?

Comment: CBroe, I thought I did, but initializedit like $insert == array(), instead of $insert = array(). I double check everything before posting here, so I'm sorry for wasting your time with this question. I appreciate it though! Put it as an answer and I'll commend it.

Answer (score 0):

My mysql output from `$result`:

```
  +------------------------------------------+
    | group  exercise_name use_exercise        |
    +------------------------------------------+
    | Knee    Knee _1       1                  |
    | Knee    Knee _2       1                  |
    | Knee    Knee _3       0                  |
    | Knee    Knee _4       0                  |
    | Knee    Knee _5       0                  |
    | Shoulder Shoulder_1   1                  |
    | Shoulder Shoulder_2   0                  |
    | Shoulder Shoulder_3   0                  |
    | Shoulder Shoulder_4   0                  |
    | Shoulder Shoulder_5   0                  |
    | Ankle   Ankle _1      1                  |
    | Ankle   Ankle _2      0                  |
    | Ankle   Ankle _3      0                  |

+------------------------------------------+
```

The rest of the PHP code is really not relevant to this. I ended up getting this result from it. My only problem is passing everything to the array. I've tested with another PHP file and it printed how it was supposed to, so I don't know what is happening.